# upload an file an save to database via slick

Tags: scala, playframework, slick

I want to upload an file and save that file to the database.
I am using play framework and slick.
I can't find any examples how to write the tablequery and how to save a file in my database (Postgres).

The Play documentation describes the way how to upload the file:

```
def upload = Action(parse.multipartFormData) { request =>
  request.body.file("picture").map { picture =>
    import java.io.File
    val filename = picture.filename
    val contentType = picture.contentType
    val file = picture.ref.file

    //Here I have to save file, right?

    Ok("File uploaded")
  }.getOrElse {
    Redirect(routes.Application.index).flashing(
      "error" -> "Missing file")
  }
}
```

Can anybody give me an example or an hint where to look at, please?
I am not sure, what the data type for my model would be, as well.

So lets say, there is a PictureDao:

```
trait PictureDao with PictureComponent with HasDatabaseConfig[JdbcProfile] {
  import driver.api._

}

trait PictureComponent {
  protected val dbConfig = DatabaseConfigProvider.get[JdbcProfile]("postgres")(Play.current)
  protected val driver: JdbcProfile
  import driver.api._
  import com.github.tototoshi.slick.JdbcJodaSupport._

  class PictureTable(tag: Tag) extends Table[Picture](tag, "picture") {
    def userId = column[Option[UUID]]("userid", O.PrimaryKey)
    def photo = column[Blob]("photo")
    def date = column[DateTime]("date")
    def * = (userId, photo, date) <> ((Picture.apply _).tupled, Picture.unapply)
  }
  // table query definitions
  val pictureTable = TableQuery[PictureTable]
}
```

What kind of type would the "photo" be on my Picture class?

Looks like an easy tasks. I wonder why it is so complicated...

Comment: It is common to save the file to disk and just persist the URL of this file in the database. That would work. But it has one caveat: I am strongly dependend of a (stateful) environment where the application is running on. If this environment (docker image etc..) is build on every deployment as well, all data are lost. So, I guess persisting the image into the db is still the way to go..
Any opinions?

Comment: Have you found any solutions to this question? If any, would you mind adding it as an answer?